# Java programming - Class and method

Tags: java, class, methods, equals, contains

I am new to Java programming and I had a task in class. 
So the main thing was I had to make a public class named BankAccount with these 3: int number, String owner, int amount.

Then I had to make an array of 10 with this class and fill it up (the owner names were Name1, Name2, etc.).

Then I had to make a String array of 5 with 5 names in it (for example: "James", "Jack", etc.)

and then I had to kind of "modify" the owner names so that my program will attach one of the 5 names randomly to the end of the current owner names.
So it will be like this for example: Name2Jack, Name3James, etc.

I successfully did all of this.
But then.

My teacher told me to make another method which will decide, how many names do I have out of the 10 ownernames in which name X is present.

So I did this:

```
public static int Count(BankAccount[] accounts, String name){
   int number=0;
       for (i=0; i<accounts.length, i++){
          if(accounts[i].owner.contains(name)==true)
              number++;
         }
   return number;
```

}

At least if I remember correctly, it was this. Or something similar like that.
And this worked as well.

But then, my teacher said, how would I do it with not .contains but with .equals ?
And if I would do it with that, would I need 1 or 2 "=" marks?

I had no idea what she means, like I dont know how to do it with .equals... because the owner names are like Name1Jack for example..

She told me I would need 1 "=" mark instead of 2, and that I should look after this for the next class.

Can you guys actually tell me what she meant with this ".equals" method instead of the .contains one?
How could I do this with .equals , and I dont get it why would I need 1 "=" mark instead of 2 whatsoever.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If you don't know what your teacher wanted, what the assignment is, how can we help?

Comment: I would need to do the same thing what I did with .contains , but instead of that, do it with .equals. But how is that possible, if the owner names are not like "james" and stuff, but "Name1James" for example.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to just change this one line:

**From:**

```
if (accounts[i].owner.contains(name) == true)
```

**To:**

```
if (accounts[i].owner.equals(name))
```

Here is a sample code with both variations:

```
public class BankAccountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount[] bankAccounts = new BankAccount[5];
        bankAccounts[0] = (new BankAccount(1, "Name1James", 1000));
        bankAccounts[1] = (new BankAccount(2, "Name2Jack", 2000));
        bankAccounts[2] = (new BankAccount(3, "Name3Henry", 3000));
        bankAccounts[3] = (new BankAccount(4, "Name4Jack", 4000));
        bankAccounts[4] = (new BankAccount(5, "Name5James", 5000));

        System.out.println("Check A:");
        System.out.println(BankAccountDemo.Count(bankAccounts, "James"));
        System.out.println(BankAccountDemo.Count2(bankAccounts, "James"));

        System.out.println("Check B:");
        System.out.println(BankAccountDemo.Count(bankAccounts, "Name5James"));
        System.out.println(BankAccountDemo.Count2(bankAccounts, "Name5James"));

    }

    public static int Count(BankAccount[] accounts, String name) {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if (accounts[i].owner.contains(name) == true) {
                number++;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }

    public static int Count2(BankAccount[] accounts, String name) {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            if (accounts[i].owner.equals(name)) {
                number++;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Run output is:

```
Check A:
2
0
Check B:
1
1
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. Maybe I forgot something: String name (which you give to your Count method) can only be "James", "Henry" or "Jack" (in your example), it can not be the 'Name1James' for example, etc. Will it work with this way as well, if we only give "James" as String name? Or is there something else you need to change in order to make that work? I feel like .equals is checking the whole string, so it would give us a "false" result if .equals only checks "james", while the string in the array is "Name1james".

Comment: If you see the output of Check A, the 2nd value is 0. That is result of checking argument "James" with names stored in BankAccounts using .equals(), and since an exact match can't be found, it returns 0.

Comment: I think your assignment is about overriding equals() and hashCode() methods for the BankAccount class. This is required when you want to have your custom logic to compare two Java objects. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html